# SQL SERVER 2008 Select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, vb6

I have a little issue that i'm trying to resolve. I'm working on a function in VB6, using SQL SERVER 2008 for storage. Here is my issue....

I enter data for a client, ClientID, ClientTask, TaskID, FromDate, ToDate in tblClientInformation.

So let's say I enter client data as such:

```
ClientID  ClientTask  TaskID   FromDate   ToDate
177       Acct        21       7/28/2016  8/3/2016
179       Acct        21       7/28/2016  8/4/2016
```

So here's my issue - I have only 2 spot open for this TaskID. So before I enter any one of these records I check the count like this...

```
Select ClientID from tblClientInformation where taskID=21 and FromDate>='7/28/2016'
```

In this case I'd get a count of 2. However my issue comes up when I someone tries to add another records on 7/29/2016 (my from date is always today) so in this case the system would do this....

```
Select clientId from tblClientinformation where taskID=21 and FromDate>='7/29/2016'
```

But now it's showing up as no records, since the FROMDATES in SQL SERVER are all before 7/29/2016 (as can be seen in my table data). But I want to make sure that when I enter a client for FROMdate = 7/29/2016, there is no ClientID's in between the FromDate and ToDate. So basically if I try to add a client today on 7/29/2016 - it should show me 2 clientID's since 7/29/2016 is in between the FromDate and ToDate.

Comment: For example in this case I add row with date `8/4/2016` that is is only in second row in `ToDate` field? Should it show only 1 record in that case? If date is `8/5/2016`- no records?

Comment: If you add 8/4/2016 then it should show only one fields, because its inbetween FromDate and Todate. And for 8/5/2016 - no records because it's not inbetween the fromdate and todate.

Comment: @gofr1 I'm only trying to show records where entered Date is between the fromDate and toDate

Comment: I add an answer. That should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query to show all records where entered `Date` is between the `FromDate` and `ToDate` (literaly):

```
DECLARE @DateToCheck date = '8/4/2016'

SELECT FieldsYouNeed
FROM tblClientinformation 
WHERE taskID=21 and @DateToCheck between FromDate and ToDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use

```
SELECT clientId 
FROM tblClientinformation 
WHERE taskID=21 
  AND FromDate <='7/29/2016' 
  AND ToDate >= '7/29/2016';
```

In this case the from date of 7/28 is less than the today date, and the to date of 8/31 is greater than the today date and will return the two records.